# Поворот триггера unity3d

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

У меня есть триггер, который нормально реагирует на столкновения, но когда я вращаю его таким кодом:

```
target = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, beginAngle);
rotationer.transform.localRotation = target;
```

То во время вращения он перестает реагировать на столкновения.

Не подскажете, как можно решить данную проблему?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для поворота используйте вращение через [`Rigidbody.MoveRotation`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MoveRotation.html), тогда объект будет поворачиваться физикой, а сейчас он у вас фактически телепортируется в новое положение поэтому и столкновений нет.